# Dropdown select list in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Does anybody know how to select the contents of one take from a different view in CakePHP?

I have a take `itemgroups` that has 2 fields `ID` and `Description`. I need to make a down down list in the item add page but I can not find a good way to get all of the values from another table into an array to put into the page.

Below I have also listed my models for each.

```
<?php

class Item extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Item';
    var $belongsTo = 'Itemgroup';
}

?>
```

```
class Itemgroup extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Itemgroup';
    var $hasOne = array('Item');
    var $validate = array(
        'description' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
}

?>
```

Comment: Please mark the answer correct or re-clarify the question to get a more specific answer. Thx

Answer (score 23):

Assuming your model is User and the field you want to use is a list of US states (for example)...

In your controller:

```
$this->set('states',$this->State->find('list'));
```

and in your view:

```
<?php echo $form->input('User.state',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$states)); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code to display a select dropdown.

```
<?php echo $form->input('inputname', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$cate, 'label'=>false, 'empty'=>'Category')); ?>
```

where $cate is loaded with an array from a find('list') in the format

array(0 => 'option1', 1=>'option2', etc etc etc

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 
    $arrCategory=array(1=>"Car",2=>"Boat",3=>"Bike");
    echo $form->input('inputname', array('options'=>$arrCategory, 'label'=>false,
                                  'empty'=>'Category','selected'=>'Your Value')); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

please use

```
    //In controller
    $data=$this->Model->find('list');
    $this->set('data',$data);
```

In View :

```
    $this->Form->input('list',array("options"=>$data));
```

Comment: @Jhawins: There's nothing wrong with answering old question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this in your controller and view...

```
//In Controller:
    $data=$this->Model->find('list',array('conditions'=>array()));
    $this->set('data',$data);

//In View:

    echo $this->Form->select('field_name',$data,null,array("escape"=>false,"empty"=>"select"));
```

If you want to show initially select value in dropdown then you can pass value where use null in above line.

Answer (score 1):

In controller:

```
$Itemgroup = $this->Itemgroup->find('list',
  array(
    'fields' => array('ID','Description')
  )
);

$this->set('Itemgroup',$Itemgroup);
```

In View:

```
$form->input('itemgroup_id', array('type' => 'select','options'=> $Itemgroup));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's something like a "US States" dropdown list that is going to be repeated from page to page, consider using an [Element](http://book.cakephp.org/view/97/Elements), which you can just pass data to and you won't have to repeat all the UI code again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right solution in my opinion:
of choices `from column SET` or `ENUM` type

```
* 
* @param string $sColumn - col name
* @param string $sTable - if use other table as Model
* @return array 
*/
function fGetArrayFromSQLSet($sColumn, $sTable=null) {

    # Pokud neni urcena tabulka, pouzij tabulku modelu
    if( !$sTable ) {
        $sTable= $this->useTable;
    }

    # Nacti nastaveni daneho pole dane tabulky
    $tmpHlaseno=$this->query("SELECT COLUMN_TYPE
                    FROM information_schema.columns
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$sTable'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME = '$sColumn'
        "); //db($tmpHlaseno);
    $tmpList= $tmpHlaseno[0]['columns']['COLUMN_TYPE']; 

    # Ziskej hodnoty z nastaveni a uloz je do pole
    $sTmp= str_replace(')', '', str_replace('set(', '', str_replace('enum(', '', $tmpList)));
    $aTmp= explode(',', str_replace("'", '', $sTmp));
    foreach( $aTmp as $value ) {
        $aSetList[$value]= $value;
    }   //db($aSetList);

    return $aSetList;   
}       // END of fGetArrayFromSQLSet
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CakePHP 3.6

```
$fruits = ['1'=>'orange','2'=>'melon','3'=>'lemon','4'=>'apple'];
echo $this->Form->control('Fruit', ['options'=>$fruits, 'label'=>"select your fruit", 'value'=>'lemon']);
```

Your dropdownlist will come with 'lemon' selected by default.

This code will produce the following html:

```
<div class="input select">
  <label for="Fruit">select your fruit</label>
  <select name="Fruit" id="Fruit">
    <option value="1">orange</option>
    <option value="2">melon</option>
    <option value="3">lemon</option>
    <option value="4">apple</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You can find more info here:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls

Answer (score -7):

Or You can use this:

In Model:

```
/**
* Get list of choises from collumn SET or ENUM type
* 
* @param string $sColumn - col name
* @param string $sTable - if use other table as Model
* @return array 
*/
function fGetArrayFromSQLSet($sColumn, $sTable=null) {

    # Pokud neni urcena tabulka, pouzij tabulku modelu
    if( !$sTable ) {
        $sTable= $this->useTable;
    }

    # Nacti nastaveni daneho pole dane tabulky
    $tmpHlaseno=$this->query("SELECT COLUMN_TYPE
                    FROM information_schema.columns
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$sTable'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME = '$sColumn'
        "); //db($tmpHlaseno);
    $tmpList= $tmpHlaseno[0]['columns']['COLUMN_TYPE']; 

    # Ziskej hodnoty z nastaveni a uloz je do pole
    $sTmp= str_replace(')', '', str_replace('set(', '', str_replace('enum(', '', $tmpList)));
    $aTmp= explode(',', str_replace("'", '', $sTmp));
    foreach( $aTmp as $value ) {
        $aSetList[$value]= $value;
    }   //db($aSetList);

    return $aSetList;   
}       // END of fGetArrayFromSQLSet
```

In Controller:

```
# TB ENUM fields 
$aFields= array('order', '<TB_col_SET_type>', '<TB_col_SET_type>', .... ); 
    foreach ($aFields as $sFieldName ) {
        $this->set(Inflector::pluralize(Inflector::variable($sFieldName)),  $this->PHlaseni->fGetArrayFromSQLSet($sFieldName) ); 
    }
```

In View is enought:

```
<?=$form->input('order')?>
<?=$form->input('<TB_col_SET_type>')?>
```