# Validate multiple fields from other model in HABTM relationship

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.4

**What I'using:**

cakephp version 2.4.1

**What I have:**

table **token_maps** has attributes (**id**, name, account_no, charge_code, type)

table **token_map_groups** has attributes (**id**, **token_map_id**, name, account_no, charge_code, type )

table **token_map_group_providers** has attributes (**id, token_map_group_id, provider_id**)

table **providers** has attributes (**id**, name)

**Relationship**

token_maps **hasMany** token_map_groups (ONE token map can have MANY token map group)

token_map_groups **belongsTo** token_maps

token_map_groups **HABTM** providers

token_map_group_providers **belongsTo** token_map_groups, providers

I already have add page for token_map_groups:
[image]

**What I want:**

I want there is no same choosen provider in all token map group that belongs to ONE token map.

How I can validate it?

After many thougt I'm using query that will return list of [not yet selected] provider. here's the query:

```
select id from providers where id not in (
select c.provider_id from token_maps a
select c.provider_id from token_maps a
inner join token_map_groups b ON b.token_map_id = a.id
inner join token_map_group_providers c on c.token_map_group_id=b.id
left join providers p on p.id=c.provider_id
where a.id= $id)
```

Comment: Answer for your question need many line of codes. It don't focus to relationship between models, or validate condtions in many related model.

Comment: well actualy right now I'm trying to populate provider_id that not in the list using sql query

Comment: This link maybe help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450457/cakephp-make-select-dropdown

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you... do you need to validate that, given a token_map their token_map_groups do not repeat any provider?

Comment: yes @Choma you right and finally I'm using sql query to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
Suppose you have a modal User and you want to validate User's data from Product modal then what you can do is,
 1. Create validation rule in the Product modal like,    

  public $validate = array(        
'first_name' => array(    
 'rule' => '',    
'message' => ''    
));


 2. Add user data to product data like,    
    $this->Product->data['Product'] = $this->User->data['User'];

3. And in the ProductsController,   
 if($this->Product->validates()) {

}
```