# Dropdown list from different table CakePHP

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a form that will allow the user to edit a certain order. 
I would like to be able to make a drop down list of Sales Agents that are already stored in a different table.

The foreign key is UserID (Alias for User table is SalesAgent).

This is in my view for the edit_sales_agent action:
In my controller I have this:

```
echo $this->Form->create("Order");
echo $this->Form->input("UserID");
```

I thought that a drop down list should automatically be created when I do this, but a text area is created instead.

Does anyone know what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdown select list in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450457/dropdown-select-list-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 2):

Using CakePHP naming conventions the foreign key should be `user_id` not `UserID`. If you correct this and then set the `$users` variable in your controller to be an indexed array using [`find('list')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) the form helper should automatically generate a dropdown list.

So in your controller you need to do something like:-

```
$users = $this->Order->User->find('list');
$this->set(compact('users'));
```

Then your form input:-

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
```

If you cannot rename the foreign key to conform to Cake standards then you will need to tell the form helper to use [the `$users` array for the options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select):-

```
echo $this->Form->select('UserId', $users);
```

Using CakePHP's naming conventions will make life a lot easier for you. Using your own conventions will result in you needing to constantly override the workings of the framework.